# incompatible types: int cannot be converted to IntegerProperty

Tags: javafx

Hola a todos necesito saber cual es la solución a mi problema, verán al crear la instancia:

```
Usuario a = new Usuario()
```

Marca **error** y me aparece:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to IntegerProperty

no tengo idea de como arreglarlo, agradezco la ayuda.

**Mi código:**

```
public void guardarRegistro(){
    //Crear una nueva instancia del tipo Alumno
    Usuario a = new Usuario(0,
                txtNombre.getText(),
                txtApellido.getText(),
                txtCorreo.getText(),
                                    rbtFemenino.isSelected()?"F":"M",
                                    txtNick.getText(),
                                    txtContraseña.getText(),
                                    txtTipoU.getText());    
    //Llamar al metodo guardarRegistro de la clase Alumno
    conexion.conectar();
    int resultado = a.guardarRegistro(conexion.getConnection());
    conexion.cerrarConexion();

    if (resultado == 1){
        listaUsuarios.add(a);
        //JDK 8u>40
        Alert mensaje = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        mensaje.setTitle("Registro agregado");
        mensaje.setContentText("El registro ha sido agregado exitosamente");
        mensaje.setHeaderText("Resultado:");
        mensaje.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitamos ver la clase usuario

Comment: Aqui esta https://codeshare.io/UbKVU

Comment: Revisa el enlace, no hay código.

Comment: Lo borraron, lo subí  acá https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Lpe1s1kzSN6ZI_hYcE5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu clase `Usuario` tienes definido:

`private IntegerProperty IdUsuario;`

Y al constructor le estás pasando como primer parámetro el número `0` que es de tipo `int` y no `IntegerProperty`.

```
IntegerProperty idUsuario = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

Usuario a = new Usuario(
                idUsuario,
                txtNombre.getText(),
                txtApellido.getText(),
                txtCorreo.getText(),
                rbtFemenino.isSelected() ? "F" : "M",
                txtNick.getText(),
                txtContraseña.getText(),
                txtTipoU.getText());
```